# Time complexity of simultaneous iteration

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm struggling to understand what will be the time complexity of simultaneous iteration.
If we have a function that takes two arrays and iterates over them sequentially it's obvious:

```py
def process(a: list, b: list):
    for i in range(len(a)):
      a[i]
    for i in range(len(b)):
      b[i]
```

We have `O(a.length + b.length)`

But if we have a knowing that the length of lists are the same and we do simultaneous iteration:

```py
def process(a: list, b: list):
    for i in range(len(a)):
      a[i]
      b[i]
```

Does it mean we have `O(a.length)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `a` and `b` have the same length, say `N`, you can say for sure that BOTH your examples will run in `O(N)`.

If you have instead the precondition of

- len(a) = N
- len(b) = M

Then, your first algorithm will run in `O(N+M)` and your second one will run in `O(N)` since you're limiting the iteration on the length of `a`.

It's all a matter of preconditions and constraints on the input in this case

Comment: Can I clarify your answer a bit? `O(N)` seems to have multiple meanings here.
Do you mean that if we have the same length let's say `M` - complexity is `O(M)` (a.k.a `O(N)`) 
But if we have different lengths `M` and `K` you will have complexity `O min(M, K)` that is basically `O(N)` as well but with emphasis on the corner case.
Do I understand you right?

Comment: I mean that, if we know as a precondition that the two lists have the same length (call it N, M, FOO or as we like), then both your algorithms will have a time complexity of O(N).
If we, instead, know that the two lists have different lengths say N for a and M for b, the complexity of the two algorithms will be different since in the first one you iterate over both of them completely, in the second one instead you will iterate all the elements of a (which are N) and only the first N elements of b

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I was confused by referring that the difference in complexity is `O(N)` and `O(M+N)` which makes it look like the second complexity is twice bigger (that isn't important during linear complexity, but can be for the interviewer) rather than complexity will be the smallest from `M` and `N`

Comment: @SergiiV. exactly.
In general we can assume that the two lists have different sizes, BUT if you know for sure that they are the same, then you'll have same complexity for the two algorithms you posted.
I don't agree with jsheeran answer because in general, sizes are different and like so, his algorithm should run in O(N*M) and not O(N^2)